# Could I give Java a regular expression when java should not split an string?

Tags: java, regex

Can I give the `String.split` method a parameter which tells it when it must not split the given string? In my particular case, I have text documents with lots of text and symbols. But in every file there are many different symbols. This is what I want to achieve:

```
string.split(not(A-Z,ß,ä,ö,ü));
```

So basically, I want `String.split` to only split whenever it finds a character that is not part of the German set of characters.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Please write this as an answer, as a comment might not be found by passing readers.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Okay, then I'll create a Community Wiki answer because it's actually you who deserve the reputation.

Comment: @WashingGuedes: If that's the answer for him, then it's just stringVar.split("[^A-Zßäöü]");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three tokens in regular expressions that allow you to do exactly what you want to achieve:

- `[]` creates a character class which contains all characters that are listed inside. In your particular case, you'd want this to be `[a-zßäöü]` as this character group contains all characters `a` through `z`, `ß`, `ä`, `ö` and `ü`.
- `^` negates the contents of a character class. So, using the character class from above, you'd use `[^a-zßäöü]` if you wanted to match any character that is not part of the character group.
- Additionally, adding `(?i)` in front of your regular expression causes it to be case *in*sensitive, which allows your expression to match the uppercase letters as well without having to actually add them to your expression.

So, adding those three tokens together, you get the regular expression `(?i)[^a-zßäöü]`. Now the only thing left is to put them into your `String.split` method and you're done:

```java
string.split("(?i)[^a-zßäöü]");
```

Comment: @Human Concerning the "there is a lot of whitespace in my array" - do you mean that your array contains lots of empty strings? If you want to keep that from occurring, use `String.split(String, int)` with the second parameter being -1. This keeps empty array elements from being created.

Comment: @Human The character for whitespace characters in regex is \s

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Human,

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to split a string on non-German characters?

So,

```
abcdöyüp
```

becomes

```
a, b, c, dö, yü, p
```

If that is the case, then unfortunately you need to specify the set of characters that are **non-German**, e.g. [A-Z] to split on. If you are trying to accomplish something other than this, please clarify and/or provide an example.